# I want WooCommerce to treat existing custom post types as products immediately WITHOUT re-saving each post

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I have millions of posts (using a custom post type called "case"). They each have a lot of post_meta records (using ACF). I now want woocommerce to treat these "case" CPTs as products (**without** changing their actual post type to "product"). I'm using [Reigel Gallarde's plugin](http://reigelgallarde.me/doc/woocommerce-custom-post-type-manager/) which sets up woocommerce to treat any CPTs as products. It kind of works. But the problem is that I am forced to go into each "case" post edit screen and re-save the post in order for woocommerce to finally recognize it as a product. Obviously, it is impractical to manually do this for millions of posts. So how can I otherwise trick woocommerce into recognizing these? Can I add a minimum of post meta fields or do something else in the database or in functions code in order for them to be recognized?

NOTE: A correct answer should NOT require changing the post_type of these items to "product".

Answer (score 1):

run a query in your data base:

1. make a copy of your DB.
2. run the query: `UPDATE wp_posts SET post_type = 'product' WHERE post_type = 'post';` but [using $wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).

If you don't know anything of code you can use a hook to run that query when you update one post, then you delete the code.

```
function runQuery(){
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->update(
        $wpdb->posts,
        array('post_type' => 'product'),
        array('post_type' => 'post'),
        array('%s'),
        array(''%s0)
    );

}

add_action( 'save_post', 'runQuery' );
```

Add this to functions.php

Comment: I specified that I want to accomplish this WITHOUT changing the post type to "product".